# Chef - using a for loop with SQLEOH

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a bash resource which is failing when attempting to loop through some ddl scripts. The same syntax without a for loop (and literal script name) works fine in Chef, and it all works including with the for loop in a terminal:

```
bash "run_ddl_create_tenants" do
user "#{ENV['CHEFUSER']}"
environment "PATH" => "/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/#{ENV['CHEFUSER']}/bin"
code <<-EOH
  for f in $(grep '>' /tmp/diffs/tnntdiff | cut -c 3-); do
    sqlplus "admin/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$(aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier #{ENV['CLIENTID']}-#{ENV['CTCENV']} | grep 'Address' | cut -d\\\" -f4))(PORT=#{ENV['DBPORT']}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=#{ENV['CLIENTID']}#{ENV['CTCENV']})))" <<-SQLEOH
      @#{ENV['CTC_CONFIGURATION']}/ddl/ddl_create_tenant_$f.sql
      #{ENV['DBPASSWD']}
      exit;
    SQLEOH
  done
  EOH
end
```

The errors I am getting indicate a problem with the SQLEOH delimiter and unexpected end-of-file.

```
STDERR: /tmp/chef-script20151012-25490-16o11q7: line 7: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `SQLEOH')
/tmp/chef-script20151012-25490-16o11q7: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What is the disconnection between the terminal commands and the way Chef is interpreting this resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, issue of whitespaces preceding the delimiter. Removed indentation on SQLEOH and connected successfully